# How do we prove that $a = \frac{w \cdot u}{u \cdot u}$ and $b = \frac{w \cdot v}{v \cdot v}$?

Tags: vectors

Let ***u*** and ***v*** be two fixed, but unknown non-zero orthogonal vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Consider the linear combination $ w= au + bv$, for some $a$, $b ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

Show that:

> $$a = \frac{w \cdot u}{u \cdot u}$$
> $$b = \frac{w \cdot v}{v \cdot v}$$

My hunch told me that I would probably have to use the vector projection formula which is:
$$Proj_vU = (\frac{u \cdot v}{v \cdot v}) \cdot v $$

I can prove just fine if I were to insert $a$ and $b$ to the linear equation, however, how do you get $a$ and $b$ if we were to derive them from the linear equation instead?

Comment: Just substitute $w=au+bv$ into the LHS of each of the two equations to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

It suffices to apply the inner product twice, apply its properties and use the orthogonality of $u$ and $v$.

Let us do the second case as an example:

\begin{align*}
w = au + bv \Rightarrow \langle w,v\rangle & = \langle au + bv,v\rangle = a\langle u,v\rangle + b\langle v,v\rangle = b\langle v,v\rangle
\end{align*}

Can you settle the second equation based on the previous comment?

Comment: What does the angled bracket imply?

Comment: It is a notation for inner product. If you are not used to it, you can replace my notation by yours.

Comment: Okay, but may I ask why it is ⟨au+bv,v⟩, instead of ⟨au+bv,u⟩?

Comment: @SWFS the two possibilities need to be considered. The first case is done and the second is left to you as an exercise.

Comment: Ah, alright, I understand now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SWFS You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.